# What is this time series model and how to produce it in R?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, terminology

I know that $Y_{t} = a + bY_{t-1} + \epsilon$ is named as autoregression model. I am dealing with the model like: $Y_{t} = a + bY_{t-1} + cX_{t} + dX_{t-1} + \epsilon$. I could not find any useful information when I searched "multivariate autoregression". Could anyone tell me the model name and how to do it in R?

Comment: It's called an Autoregressive distributed lag model. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lag

Comment: AR distributed lag model doesn't contain the response as predictor

Comment: Sure they do. The link was just for distributed lag models (lacking the 'autoregresive' part), but that was just to get you started. Look at the first equation here for example: http://mail.tku.edu.tw/chenyiyi/ADL.pdf That is exactly what you have, is it not?

Comment: You can fit these type of models in R using basic `lm`, but you need to create the lagged variables by hand. Package *dynlm* allows specifying lags in the formula interface, the R code for ardl(1,1) model would be `dynlm(y~L(y,1)+x+L(x,1))`. Also package *midasr* allows fitting of such models, the code would be `midas_u(y~mls(y,1,1)+mls(x,1,0:1))`.

Comment: Next time when you encounter "multivariate autoregression", you may look at "vector autoregression".

Comment: Could you clarify what "do it in R" might mean?  Do you have data you wish to fit with this model, or do you wish to create data according to this model?

Answer (score 1):

Combining comments by hejseb and mpiktas, which answer this question:

> It's called an Autoregressive distributed lag model:
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lag

> The [previous] link was just for distributed lag models (lacking the
> 'autoregresive' part), but that was just to get you started. Look at
> the first equation here for example: https://mail.tku.edu.tw/chenyiyi/ADL.pdf
> That is exactly what you have, is it not?

$-$  hejseb

> You can fit these type of models in R using basic `lm`, but you need to
> create the lagged variables by hand. Package *dynlm* allows specifying
> lags in the formula interface, the R code for ardl(1,1) model would be
> `dynlm(y~L(y,1)+x+L(x,1))`. Also package *midasr* allows fitting of such
> models, the code would be `midas_u(y~mls(y,1,1)+mls(x,1,0:1))`

$-$ mpiktas